# Function or loop to more efficiently sum up ifelse()-condition

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, if-statement, group-by

Birth length correspond to `aa$laengde` for gestational weeks `37:42` stored in `aa$uge`. I want to make a new covariate, `aa$sfga`, so that if the `aa$laengde` is lower or equal to the `5% quantile` *for the specific `aa$uge` it corresponds to*, then "short" else "long".

This works but seem too inefficient. It is basically a series of `ifelse()`-function integrated in `ifelse()`-functions, and I was considering that there must be a more efficient way, a function or a loop, to do this repetitive task.

```
aa$sfga <- 
  ifelse((aa$uge==37 & aa$laengde<=quantile(aa$laengde[aa$uge==37], probs = 0.05)), "short",
         ifelse((aa$uge==38 & aa$laengde<=quantile(aa$laengde[aa$uge==38], probs = 0.05)), "short", 
                ifelse((aa$uge==39 & aa$laengde<=quantile(aa$laengde[aa$uge==39], probs = 0.05)), "short", 
                       ifelse((aa$uge==40 & aa$laengde<=quantile(aa$laengde[aa$uge==40], probs = 0.05)), "short", 
                              ifelse((aa$uge==41 & aa$laengde<=quantile(aa$laengde[aa$uge==41], probs = 0.05)), "short", 
                                     ifelse((aa$uge==42 & aa$laengde<=quantile(aa$laengde[aa$uge==42], probs = 0.05)), "short", "long"))))))
```

Data sample

```
aa <- structure(list(uge = c(37L, 41L, 42L, 40L, 40L, 42L, 41L, 39L, 
41L, 41L, 41L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 39L, 41L, 41L, 40L, 38L, 41L, 
39L, 40L, 42L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 41L, 40L, 39L, 40L, 39L, 38L, 40L, 
41L, 39L, 41L, 39L, 42L, 42L, 41L, 40L, 37L, 41L, 39L, 38L, 39L, 
39L, 40L, 40L, 42L, 42L, 42L, 41L, 41L, 40L, 42L, 41L, 39L, 41L, 
39L, 40L, 41L, 41L, 40L, 41L, 39L, 41L, 40L, 41L, 38L, 40L, 39L, 
39L, 42L, 39L, 39L, 42L, 41L, 40L, 40L, 39L, 41L, 40L, 40L, 41L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 39L, 41L, 39L, 39L, 40L, 40L, 42L, 40L, 40L, 
39L), laengde = c(52L, 58L, 53L, 55L, 52L, 56L, 57L, 50L, 52L, 
54L, 56L, 54L, 52L, 52L, 53L, 52L, 57L, 53L, 55L, 52L, 54L, 51L, 
51L, 54L, 52L, 53L, 50L, 55L, 48L, 54L, 51L, 50L, 56L, 55L, 53L, 
52L, 53L, 51L, 53L, 53L, 58L, 54L, 52L, 49L, 54L, 52L, 52L, 50L, 
47L, 55L, 58L, 55L, 54L, 52L, 53L, 52L, 54L, 51L, 50L, 54L, 50L, 
52L, 55L, 52L, 52L, 54L, 50L, 53L, 53L, 51L, 53L, 57L, 52L, 52L, 
46L, 52L, 49L, 55L, 55L, 53L, 58L, 51L, 47L, 55L, 52L, 56L, 50L, 
53L, 54L, 50L, 53L, 54L, 52L, 52L, 54L, 55L, 54L, 50L, 52L, 54L
)), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I personally would create a second `data.frame` or some form of dict map. That said, you could probably write up a function that does the mapping since you have a common theme (quantile for instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `group_by` with `dplyr`.
The quantiles are calculated within each group :

```
library(dplyr)
aa %>% group_by(uge) %>%
       mutate(sfga = if_else(laengde <= quantile(laengde, probs = 0.05),"short","long")) %>%
       ungroup

# A tibble: 100 x 3
# Groups:   uge [6]
     uge laengde sfga 
   <int>   <int> <chr>
 1    37      52 short
 2    41      58 long 
 3    42      53 long 
 4    40      55 long 
 5    40      52 long 
 6    42      56 long 
 7    41      57 long 
 8    39      50 short
 9    41      52 long 
10    41      54 long 
# ... with 90 more rows
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe @Waldi answered your question, so I just want to address the nested `ifelse` statement. If you ever consider that approach, I would advise you to use `case_when`. An example

```
aa <- aa %>% 
  mutate(sfga = case_when(
    aa$week == 37 & quantile(aa$length[aa$week == 37], probs = 0.05) ~ 'short',
    aa$week == 38 & quantile(aa$length[aa$week == 38], probs = 0.05) ~ 'short',
    ...,
    TRUE ~ 'long'
  ))
```

But like I said, Waldi seems to have answered your question.